# Uninstall old Android SDK versions

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I installed Android SDK and it's taking almost 7 GB on my (relatively small) SSD.

When I open `Android SDK Manager` I can see that everything is installed even older API versions.

[image]

Same thing for the `Extras`:

[image]

Can I safely un-install all the versions and only keep the latest one (API 17 in my case) ?

I use Andoid SDK Tools to develop Android Apps with eclipse.

Thank you.

Comment: You may still want to retain some of the older SDK's so as to try your apps on lower platform. I personally keep GB(API 10), ICS(API 14) and JB(API 17).

Comment: Also what you can try is just move the whole android SDK folder to a new location with relatively large storage, and then specify the new path in preferences in eclipse. Will save you some bandwidth, in case you later need those API's. My friend just copies from mine. Data here is very costly :(

Comment: Thank you very much.. so if i keep only API 17 i will not be able to delpoy to old devices ?

Comment: You can deploy it, but you would have to mention it(that you want to run on lower APIs) on your manifest file. Also any API above the targeted device will not run and will interfere with your app design. Search for android TargetSDK version and MinimunSDK version.

Comment: thank you. If you post this as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just delete the packages you want to uninstall.

You may still want to retain some of the older SDK's so as to try your apps on lower platform. I personally keep GB(API 10), ICS(API 14) and JB(API 17).

Also what you can try is just move the whole android SDK folder to a new location with relatively large storage, and then specify the new path in preferences in eclipse. Will save you some bandwidth, in case you later need those API's. My friend just copies from mine. Data here is very costly :(

You can deploy it, but you would have to mention it(that you want to run on lower APIs) on your manifest file. Also any API above the targeted device will not run and will interfere with your app design. Search for android TargetSDK version and MinimunSDK version.

Comment: Is this possible with Android Studio too? Also, are you still using Eclipse ADT?

Comment: So those older SDKs are only needed for local emulator to run older APIs to test your app? They are not needed to build or deploy your app for older APIs, correct?

Answer (score 25):

As for the current version (Feb 2019) here is way that works from within Android Studio:

1. Open the SDK Manager (Tools -> SDK Manager).
2. There you see all available platforms and in "Name" a box which
   shows Installed [✓], Update available [–] and Not installed [  ] platforms.

[image]

3. If you klick on that box you can change the status. Click until it is empty and a red x shows up. Then press Apply. The platform will be uninstalled then.

[image]

Comment: I had to "show package details" 1st - as I only had the SDKs, then I could remove

Answer (score 19):

Select the packages that you want to uninstall[image] and click delete packages button.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I know how to uninstall them, the question is, are they required or not .. can I remove them safely.

Comment: Now the deletion of SDKs can be done in Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK. Click to see each SDK details. Unmark checkbox and click in Apply.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the android command line tool `sdkmanager` to do this instead of the UI, this is the way to do it.

## Prepare

Make sure that `sdkmanager` doesn't complain about `repositories.cfg` missing:

```
mkdir -p ~/.android && touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
```

Also make sure that you are using Java 8 by calling `java -version`, otherwise `sdkmanager` won't work (as of time of writing). Using Java 8 can be solved in many different ways, e.g:

- Linux: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
- macOS using SDKMAN!: `sdk use java <VERSION>`
- Other way

## Use

For help with all the commands run `sdkmanager --help`

For listing available components:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

For installing a component:

```
sdkmanager --install "build-tools;28.0.3"
```

For uninstalling a component:

```
sdkmanager --uninstall "build-tools;26.0.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Android SDK from Visual Studio Installer and then installing it again did resolve my problem and made the Android SDK options enable for me.

Goto VS Installer, go down to the SDK portion and uncheck **Java SE Development Kit (version)** and **Android SDK setup (API level 25)** from the individual component options and click on modify.

When they're gone, install them again following the same steps.

[image: Image to get the hint]