# Uninstalling selected parts of Android SDK on the command line

Tags: android, command-line, continuous-integration, android-build

This is related to ["Uninstall old Android SDK versions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182377/uninstall-old-android-sdk-versions), except I'd want to do it on a headless Linux CI server (short on disk space).

**Does the `android` command line tool provide options for removing older parts of the SDK?** With a quick look, the only things it can delete are AVDs. Did I overlook something?

Alternatively, I guess I could just manually delete stuff from under SDK_HOME. But what things are safe to delete? Other candidates than these?

- I only need to support API level 14 and up, so I suppose I can delete
  stuff under `platforms/` like `android-3` and `android-4`.
- `docs` (800MB), `samples` (300MB)
- How about `system-images`? Do I need e.g. `android-18/armeabi-v7a/` and `android-18/x86/` if I only want to do automated APK builds (no emulator stuff) using Gradle (and Ant)?

At least upon deleting `docs` completely, the next time I ran `android update sdk --no-ui`, it started fetching them again:

```
   Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 1
```

Can I avoid `update` adding back parts of the SDK that I threw away?

Disclaimer: yes, disk is cheap and really I should just add more. But *right now on this particular server* (8.5G disk) I don't have that option, yet I'd still like to get it to run Android 19 builds...

Comment: Not sure whether you're using Windows or Linux (or something else)

Comment: First sentence of the question: "[...] on a headless Linux CI server"

Answer (score 4):

From what I've been able to gather, you can just delete directories in `/platforms` `/skins` and `/system-images`

Answer (score 3):

Anything except tools/ can be re-installed generally with an

```
android list sdk -a
```

and

```
android update sdk --no-ui -a --filter <#index>
```

I will often blow away my add-ons/ and build-tools/ folders and reinstall my add-ons/ and build-tools/. If you need to automate accepting the license, another little trick is the following, at least if you're installing them one at a time:

```
android update sdk --no-ui -a --filter <#index> 0<<EOF
y
EOF
```

The "android" command itself lives within the "SDK Tools" package or tools/ directory, so you can't remove that, because then you can't install anything else. I also generally wouldn't remove platform-tools/, as then you can't build anything, unless you're installing a new/older version. If you look under <sdk-folder>/SDK Readme.txt, you will see the following in the first paragraph to confirm this:

> Welcome to the Android SDK!
>
> The Android SDK archive initially contains only the basic SDK tools. It does not contain an Android platform or any third-party libraries. In fact, it doesn't even have all the tools you need to develop an application.
>
> In order to start developing applications, you must install the Platform-tools and at least one version of the Android platform, using the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to download just the parts that you need. Doing a `android update sdk --no-ui` without other parameters downloads everything, and thus is time-consuming and wasteful.

The `--filter` parameter to determine the packages that you need, and using them each time you want to do an update. There's a more detailed explanation on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23196528/3063884) (and even more on the `android` command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682241/3063884)).

If periodically changing the components that are needed (e.g. targeting a different platform), you could create a script that deletes the components under the various folders that are not needed (e.g. APIs under `android-sdk-linux/platforms`) and then re-create with just the components that you want.

The `android list sdk -e` command will give an extended list of packages that can be used with the `--filter` parameter, and thus allows installation of just specific components.

After reviewing [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674626/3063884) automated way to use the `expect` command to automatically accept the license prompts, I ended up with this to install and update the components that I need, without downloading everything else (on Ubuntu):

```
expect -c '
set timeout -1;
spawn /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --filter tools,build-tools-20.0.0,platform-tools,android-16,extra-android-support,extra-android-m2repository;
expect {
    "Do you accept the license" { exp_send "y\r" ; exp_continue }
    eof
}
'
```

Note the components `tools,build-tools-20.0.0,platform-tools,android-16,extra-android-support,extra-android-m2repository` specified with the `--filter` parameter that restrict the download to just these parts.

Running this script once downloads just those components. Running again determines that nothing needs updating, but does give a confusing set of messages:

```
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'tools'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-20.0.0'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'android-16'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-support'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

These messages just mean that nothing was updated -- components included in the `--filter` specification aren't actually uninstalled.