# Remove Android SDK packages from command line

Tags: android, linux, sdk

is there a way to remove selected package (e.g. "Samples" for each API level) from command line?
I'm using Linux.
I'm aware of the answer [Uninstalling selected parts of Android SDK on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775404/uninstalling-selected-parts-of-android-sdk-on-the-command-line) but it doesn't quite cover all the topic.

Or is it safe to delete the folders without using any android tool?

Comment: The Android installation is actually pretty nice about being simple file-state on disk, such that you can install packages by manually unzipping them and remove pieces you don't need and it should pretty much work, unless you actually try to make reference to something you removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Chris Stratton said in his comment, the answer is:

Yes, it is safe to manually delete folders in the android sdk.

Answer (score 2):

**Uninstall android-sdk:**

```
sudo apt-get remove android-sdk
```

**Uninstall android-sdk and it's dependent packages:**

```
sudo apt-get autoremove android-sdk
```