# How can I delete additional tools from the sdk folder in android

Tags: android

I have android studio 1.3 and my `sdk` folder is in full update. But I do not want to have `API18`, `API19` and the higher `API` in my android studio. Because I do not need them. Please say me that if I do not want to use the `API18` to higher,What things should I delete from the `sdk` folder exactly?

Comment: Should be the same process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182377/uninstall-old-android-sdk-versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Force Delete you can Make It Simple By Using SDK Manager, Just Open Sdk manager, Mark Those Installed API which you want to uninstall and Click on Uninstall Package. It Should be Uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Studio SDK manager, click on the `Show package details` checkbox in the bottom right corner, then untick the boxes for all the old SDK versions/emulators/documentation etc that you want to delete, and hit `Apply`.

You can safely delete any files for older SDK's on the `SDK Platforms` page, but I'd advise leaving everything on the `SDK Tools` page installed as these don't take up much space, and for the most part are not platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

Run your SDK Manager, select all the tools you want to uninstall, and click on the "Delete Packages" button, this will remove all the tools you selected.